# Codeigniter Dynamic Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Hi i wont to make something like that.

http:// example.com/ - Main Controller

http:// example.com/rules/ - Main Controller where content get from database, but if not exist
return 404 page. (It's ok, isn't problem.)

But if i have subfolder in application/controlles/rules/
I want to redirect it to Main Contorller at Rules folder.

This follow code can solve problem, but i don't know how it right realise.
At routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$dirtest = $route['(:any)'];

if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$dirtest)) {
$route['(:any)'] = $dirtest.'/$1';
} else {
$route['(:any)'] = 'main/index/$1';
}
```

---

Ok, what I have:

controllers/main.php

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('main_model');
        }

    public function index($method = null)
    {
        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$method)) {
            // Need re-rout to the application/controllers/$method/
        } else {
            if ($query = $this->main_model->get_content($method)) {
                $data['content'] = $query[0]->text;
                // it shows at views/main.php
            } else {
                show_404($method);
            }
        }
        $data['main_content'] = 'main';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }

}
```

---

**Updated Again** (routes.php):
So, seem's like what i search (work example):

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';


$subfolders = glob(APPPATH.'controllers/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach ($subfolders as $folder) {
    $folder = preg_replace('/application\/controllers\//', '', $folder);
    $route[$folder] = $folder.'/main/index/';
    $route[$folder.'/(:any)'] = $folder.'/main/$1';
}

$route['(:any)'] = 'main/index/$1';
```

But, in perfectly need some like this:

http:// example.com/1/2/3/4/5/6/...

1. Folder "controllers" has subfolder "1"?
2. YES: Folder "1" has subfolder "2"?
3. NO: Folder "1" has controller "2.php"?
4. NO: Controller "controllers/1/main.php" has function "2"?
5. YES: redirect to http:// example.com/1/2/ - where 3,4,5 - parameters..

It is realy nice, when you have structure like:

```
http://example.com/blog/ - recent blog's posts
http://example.com/blog/2007/ - recent from 2007 year blog's posts
http://example.com/blog/2007/06/ - same with month number
http://example.com/blog/2007/06/29/ - same with day number
http://example.com/blog/web-design/ - recent blog's post's about web design
http://example.com/blog/web-design/2007/ - blog' posts about web design from 2007 years.
http://example.com/blog/current-post-title/ - current post
```

Same interesting i find http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/97024/#490613

Comment: Can you post an example of the kinds of re-routing you are trying to do?

Comment: Olezaika: I find the [codeigniter docs about routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) are quite good.

Comment: No, you don't understand what i want. In two words i need: If I create some folder like "new_folder" at controllres, then in routes.php append string "$route['new_folder/(:any)'] = 'new_folder/$1'"

Comment: @Olezaika: I've added an answer, I know that the docs don't cover your specific case, it's was just meant for some help.

Comment: however, thanks, but i read it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't thoroughly read your question, but this immediately caught my attention:

```
if (is_dir($path . '/' . $folder)) {
    echo "$route['$folder/(:any)'] = '$folder/index/$1';"; //<---- why echo ???
}
```

Honestly I'm not sure why this didn't cause serious issues for you in addition to not working.

You don't want to `echo` the route here,  that will just try to print the *string* to screen, it's not even interpreted as PHP this way. There are also some issues with quotes that need to be remedied so the variables can be read as variables, not strings. Try this instead:

```
if (is_dir($path . '/' . $folder)) {
    $route[$folder.'/(:any)'] = $folder.'/index/$1';
}
```

**Aside**: I'd like to offer some additional resources that are not *directly* related to your problem, but should help you nonetheless with a solution:

- Preferred way to remap calls to controllers: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping
- Easier way to scan directories: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: Yeah, thank's it's realy what i need. Other thank for glob() function.

Comment: Just use `glob(APPPATH.'controllers/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)` if you only want the *directories*. I think there's an easier way to do all of this without the directory scan, but I'm not 100% sure what it is you're after.

Comment: Great! Updated post with globe();

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say why the registering of your routes fails. From your code I can see that you're not registering the routes (you just echo them), additionally I see that the usage of variables in strings are used inconsistently. Probably you mixed this a bit, the codeigniter documentation about routes is not precise on it either (in some minor points, their code examples are not really syntactically correct, but overall it's good).

I suggest you first move the logic to register your dynamic routes into a function of it's own. This will keep things a bit more modular and you can more easily change things and you don't pollute the global namespace with variables.

Based on this, I've refactored your code a bit. It does not mean that this works (not tested), however it might make things more clear when you read it:

```
function register_dynamic_routes($path, array &$route)
{
    $nodes = scandir($path);
    if (false === $nodes)
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Path parameter invalid. scandir("$path") failed.', $path));
    }

    foreach ($nodes as $node)
    {
        if ($node === '.' or $node === '..')
            continue
            ;

        if (!is_dir("{$path}/{$node}")
            continue
            ;

        $routeDef = "{$folder}/(:any)";
        $routeResolve = "{$folder}/index/\$1";
        $route[$routeDef] = $routeResolve;

        # FIXME debug output
        echo "\$route['{$routeDef}'] = '{$routeResolve}';";
    }
}

$path = APPPATH.'controllers/';
register_dynamic_routes($path, $route);
$route['(:any)'] = 'main/index/$1';
```

Next to this you probably might not want to shift everything onto the `index` action, but a `dynamic` action instead. Furthermore, you might want to have a base controller that is delegating everything into the sub-controllers instead of adding the routes per controller. But that's up to you. The example above is based on the directory approach you outlined in your question.

**Edit:** Additional information is available in the [Controllers section](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) next to the [URI Routing section](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: Well, nice, but not work, like you say. But, you nice explain all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All this seems kind of complicated.

Plus, if you have hundreds (or thousands or more?) of possible routes in a database you may not want to load all of them into the "$routes" array every time any page loads in your application.

Instead, why not just do this?

last line of routes.php:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'vanity';
```

Controller file: Vanity.php:

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Vanity extends MY_Controller {

/**
 * Vanity Page controller.
 *
 */

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}


public function index()
{
    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $url = str_replace("/index.php/", "", $url);

    // you could check here if $url is valid. If not, then load 404 via:
    //
    //  show_404();
    //
    // or, if it is valid then load the appropriate view, redirect, or
    // whatever else it is you needed to do!


    echo "Hello from page " . $url;
    exit;



}


}


?>
```